# Passenger and Nginx unable to run rails application in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have a ubuntu EC2 instance configured with rvm and psql after which I cloned my rails application on the EC2 instance via bitbucket.
Following this digital ocean's [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) I installed passenger and nginx on my instance and set `passenger_app_env development;` inside my server configurations.
Now that I would like to use the application in production mode, I removed this line from the config and currently my server configs are as follows:

```
    server {
       #listen 80 default_server;
        listen   443 ssl;
        ssl         on;
        server_name **.**.**.**;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/ubuntu/my_app/public;
        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app.key;
}

server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    **.***.**.**;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The app is still running in the development environment as when I execute `Rails.env.production?` in the console I get false result, shouldn't passenger implicitly assume that the application is in production mode now that I have removed the setting mentioning the development environment?   Any sort of help with be appreciated. Thanks a lot. Also after every change I make in the config file I also run `sudo nginx -s reload` and `sudo service nginx restart`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add this to the `server` block of your configuration after `passenger_enabled on`:

```
passenger_app_env production;
```